# DatabaseType not found for product name: [Tibero]

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-batch, tibero

While trying to setup a Spring boot - spring batch project, I am running into an error stating:

I have checked the spring batch supported database but Tibero is not in the list.

Is there any other way to make this work with pointing Tibero DB...

Please refer the below ERROR Log.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name: [Tibero]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromProductName(DatabaseType.java:84) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:123) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:129) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check `DatabaseType` it wont support your database (Tibero).

```
public enum DatabaseType {

    DERBY("Apache Derby"),
    DB2("DB2"),
    DB2VSE("DB2VSE"),
    DB2ZOS("DB2ZOS"),
    DB2AS400("DB2AS400"),
    HSQL("HSQL Database Engine"),
    SQLSERVER("Microsoft SQL Server"),
    MYSQL("MySQL"),
    ORACLE("Oracle"),
    POSTGRES("PostgreSQL"),
    SYBASE("Sybase"),
    H2("H2"),
    SQLITE("SQLite");
}
```

These are the databases supported by spring batch out of the box.
But you can register non standard database as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository)

Since Tibero is fully compatible with oracle you can create `TiberoBatchConfigurer` like following,

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class TiberoBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

  public TiberoBatchConfigurer() {
      super();
  }

  public TiberoBatchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource) {
      super(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }
}
```